Pi becomes inaccurate with increasing the number of samples
When I change the value on line 28(which I pointed out with an arrow) from 0.00001 to 0.000001 the value of Pi becomes inaccurate. It's counterintuitive to me as to how increasing precision will make the value wrong? The program is simply supposed to calculate pi using the integral of 4 / (1 + x*x) over 0 to 1.
#include <iostream>

void fourOverX2(float& value, 
        const float lowerLimit, 
        const float upperLimit,
        const float dx)
{
    std::cout << "Values Sent: \n" 
    << lowerLimit << "\n" << upperLimit 
    << "\n" << dx << std::endl;

    value = 0;

    float x = lowerLimit, numerator = 4 * dx;

    while(x < upperLimit)
    {
        value += numerator / (1 + x * x);
        x += dx;
    }
}


int main()
{
    float value;

    fourOverX2(value, 0, 1, 0.000001); // <---- doubt here

    std::cout << "PI: " << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}



floats suck. They run out of precision pretty fast, and the noise is probably killing you. Try again with double and see if you get better results.

Side note: updating value by reference rather than returning it results in some clunky- looking code and may result in people using the function incorrectly.

Briefly, when dx is small, the float x is inadequate to adequately track all the incremental additions to x. You can see this by rewriting the loop as float numerator = 4 * dx; for (float i = 0, x = lowerLimit; x < upperLimit; x = lowerLimit + ++i*dx). That tracks the increments without error (i is always an integer value, incremented with no rounding error until it passes 2^24) and calculates x anew each iteration instead of accumulating rounding errors. This brings the result to 3.14265, showing much of the error was caused by this cumulative incrementing of x.

Some error remains, because value is also inadequate. Changing it to double brings the result to 3.14159. This even though numerator and 1 + x * x remain in float.

Using N steps of size dx in left Riemann sums gives a method error of size dx and a accumulated floating point error of (relative) size N*mu. These balance at the minimum error which gives dx ~ sqrt(mu).
For 32bit floating point mu=2^-23, so the minimum error should occur for dx about 5*10^-4. Your two probes are well in the region of accumulated floating point.
Using 64bit floating point will shift the optimal step size to 10^-8. I'd recommend using a better integration scheme. With trivial modifications you can get the midpoint and trapezoidal methods. Still accessible should be the 4th order Simpson quadrature method. With higher order methods you get better accuracy and also the optimal error at larger step sizes.

Do you have reference materials for your first paragraph? I find it fascinating and want to read more. Also, by "accessible" do you mean simple in implementation/concept, but that there are better alternatives?

@PasserBy pick a book on calculus & numeric calculations from the nearest academic library. Some university courses have practical applications.

Yes to "accesible", next there are the Romberg integration scheme and, in another direction, adaptive grid refinement.

The problem here has to do with floating point accuracy and error accumulation. In short, floats are losing precision. If you changed every float to a double, you would get a much improved result.
I thought it would be fun to look at explicit envelopes coming from error accumulation. To do this, I'm using the arb library for arbitrary precision ball arithmetic. Arb uses intervals instead of single numbers, and will track possible error loss due to finite precision. (In short, the answer is guaranteed to be contained within the specified interval, but the endpoints of the interval will slowly grow worse due to precision loss).
Translating your program to arb gives
#include <iostream>
#include "arb.h"

void approx_pi(
    arb_t value,
    arb_t dx,
    slong prec
){
  arb_t lower, upper, numerator;
  arb_init(lower); arb_init(upper); arb_init(numerator);
  arb_set_d(lower, 0.0);
  arb_set_d(upper, 1.0);
  arb_t x; arb_init(x);
  arb_t temp; arb_init(temp);

  arb_zero(value);   // value = 0
  arb_set(x, lower);
  arb_mul_ui(numerator, dx, 4, prec);

  while (arb_le(x, upper)) {
    arb_mul(temp, x, x, prec);            // temp = x*x
    arb_add_ui(temp, temp, 1, prec);      // temp = 1 + temp
    arb_div(temp, numerator, temp, prec); // temp = numerator/temp
    arb_add(value, value, temp, prec);    // value += temp
    arb_add(x, x, dx, prec);              // x += dx
  }
  arb_clear(x); arb_clear(temp); arb_clear(lower); arb_clear(upper); arb_clear(numerator);
}

int main()
{
  arb_t value, dx;
  arb_init(value); arb_init(dx);
  for (double d : {0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001}) {
    arb_set_d(dx, d);
    for (slong prec : {16, 32, 64, 128, 256}) {
      approx_pi(value, dx, prec);
      std::cout << "(d, prec) = (" << d << ", " << prec <<") : ";
      arb_printn(value, 50, 0);
      std::cout << "\n";
    }
  }
  arb_clear(value);
}

Arb is a bit verbose (and very much a C library, not a C++ library), especially due to the various memory management things. But this program mimics your program, except using d as either 1e-4, 1e-5, or 1-6 — and using 16, 32, 64, 128, or 256 bit precision objects.
The output looks like
(d, prec) = (0.0001, 16)  : [3e+0 +/- 0.559]
(d, prec) = (0.0001, 32)  : [3.14169 +/- 7.79e-6]
(d, prec) = (0.0001, 64)  : [3.14169265192313 +/- 5.59e-15]
(d, prec) = (0.0001, 128) : [3.141692651923126667649033033650765 +/- 3.43e-34]
(d, prec) = (0.0001, 256) : [3.1416926519231266676490330336507647708390521906676 +/- 3.50e-50]
(d, prec) = (1e-05, 16)   : [+/- 4.46]
(d, prec) = (1e-05, 32)   : [3.142 +/- 4.93e-4]
(d, prec) = (1e-05, 64)   : [3.1416026535731 +/- 3.77e-14]
(d, prec) = (1e-05, 128)  : [3.14160265357312673540372060439035 +/- 4.14e-33]
(d, prec) = (1e-05, 256)  : [3.1416026535731267354037206043903469959799729215627 +/- 3.69e-50]
(d, prec) = (1e-06, 16)   : [+/- 8.52]
(d, prec) = (1e-06, 32)   : [3.14 +/- 2.13e-3]
(d, prec) = (1e-06, 64)   : [3.141593653590 +/- 6.02e-13]
(d, prec) = (1e-06, 128)  : [3.14159565358962648129210986461654 +/- 9.08e-33]
(d, prec) = (1e-06, 256)  : [3.1415956535896264812921098646165452949056798821271 +/- 1.88e-50]

There is an obvious pattern where increased numbers of bits of precision for a given d leads to increased precision in the output. But notice that decreasing d for a given precision yields sizeable reductions in the output precision. This comes from adding together more values.
Finally, I'll note that one shouldn't get confused between the precision of the output and the accuracy to pi. Doing a simple integration technique like this gives poor approximations to pi, regardless of the number of bits of precision used. We shouldn't expect more than 6 digits to be correct.
Using something like midpoint approximation, or Simpson's rule, or quadrature would all give better approximations to pi.

A lot of good advice here already, just wanted to experiment to see what each of the improvement does to your code. Outputting 15 decimal digits for each test, your pure code gave me
3.11569380760193

Next I fixed the biggest issue here (as mentioned by several people already), namely error accumulation in x. Let's calculate it each time instead. The result was
3.14264631271362

The biggest improvement so far! Now changing everything to double gives me
3.14159365358979

Even better! And now to answer the initial concern, does increasing precision improve the result? I changed precision from 1e-6 to 1e-9 and it went to
3.14159266359023

Google gave me 3.14159265359 btw.
Here's the final function code after the improvements.
value = 0.; // using "." just to show it's not an integer literal
    
double x = lowerLimit;
long iteration = 0; // counter for iterations
    
while (x < upperLimit)
{
    value += 1. / (1. + x * x); // we can multiply by numerator after the cycle
    x = (++iteration) * dx; // biggest fix here, not accumulating errors over iterations
}
        
const double numerator = 4. * dx; // it was the same for each iteration...
value *= numerator;

Some things that still puzzle me though:

I was sure that when calculating sums of floating point numbers, you need to go from lowest numbers to largest. This way you have more precision, since newly added numbers don't get truncated. However when I tried reversing the cycle it only became worse.
Shall we include upper bound for x in calculations? I thought it's logical, but after changing it to <= upperLimit, the result worsened a bit. Not sure here.

Another thought is that I for some reason chose 15 digit output, which doesn't make much sense for tests with 1e-6 or 1e-8. Changing precision to 1e-9 had a sudden spike in run time so I didn't go further. It did however improve one digit (to 3.14159265458966).
Hope this was helpful.

float is a single precision binary floating point representation.  In the conversion to/from decimal values, it can accurately retain only six significant digits.
Further when you perform cumulative operations on floating point values the precision error of the incremental values accumulates too, amplifying further the error.
double is good for 15 significant decimal digits.
Ultimately binary floating point is not a suitable representation of the aim is some arbitrary level of decimal precision.
